# SQL Alphanumeric Select

Tags: sql, pattern-matching, alphanumeric

I apologize if this has been covered previously. I could not find exactly what I was looking for by searching. So I hope it's okay that I ask.

I have a column with many different types of alphanumeric values (e.g. A101, F576, AI01, etc.). What I'm wanting to do is find members of a specific portion with a specific pattern, F100 through F9999. Using between F1000 and F9999 gets me what I need. But, I don't think that's exactly the right way to go about querying for future reference.

Does anyone have any suggestions? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: you may have to write a regex, for first character to be F and remaining between number 1000-9999

Comment: What's the specific database?

Comment: If the format of all values is `<alpha><digit><digit><digit>`, `BETWEEN` is actually not a bad choice.

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? The different products are very different when it comes to supporting regex

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
SELECT * FROM THE_TABLE
WHERE THE_COLUMN LIKE 'F[1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
```

That will match `F1000` through `F9999` The key point is you can use `[0-9]` as a range.  If you want to do other patterns things like `[A-Z]` work too.

If you want `F100` to `F9999` you could do:

```
SELECT * FROM THE_TABLE
WHERE THE_COLUMN LIKE 'F[1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
OR THE_COLUMN LIKE 'F[1-9][0-9][0-9]'
```